# Etnachta on גֶשם vs. גָשם

Tags: tanach, trop-cantillation, vowels-nekudot, statistics, geshem-tal-ruach

I have heard that the reason that many siddurim print משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם with a segol is because it is more common for גשם with an etnachta to be vocalised that way, rather than with a kamatz.

Is there any statistical analysis on the commonality of one vocalisation vs. the other in Tanach when accented with an etnachta? In other words, which form is more common?

Comment: I don't understand the comparison. There are no trope notes in the Siddur (other than brachot for Haftarah). Please explain your question.

Comment: @DanF, as a general rule, an etnachta is roughly equivalent to a semi-colon, being a pausal marker, while a sof-passuk is a period. Since in the siddur (while it's not often written this way) we should render mashiv haruach as מ”ה”ו הגשם; מכלכל וכ׳ rather than גשם. מכלכל

Comment: The word is a segolete, and should (academically) properly be pronounced as a kamatz IF it is at the end of a phrase. The reverse issue surrounds Kiddush Levanah, where we invert the possuk "Tipol aleihem..." to place "ka'aven" at the start, where it should properly be pronounced "Ka'***Ev***en"

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, I'm well aware of "Ka'aven," considering that some of the folks in my kehillah discuss it every month. FWIW, I sometimes pronounce the segol, rather than the kamatz.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, I think you're actually thinking of something that was said about 'morid ha-tal' - why editors who choose non-pausal 'geshem' nonetheless use pausal 'tal' with a kamatz.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3142/759

Answer (score 5):

The word גשם occurs at an *etnachta* only in Prov 25:23, where it has a *kamatz*.  It occurs at a *sof pasuk* four times (1 Kings 18:41, 18:44, Zech 14:17, Eccl 12:2), each time with a *kamatz*.  All occurrences of גשם on lesser disjunctives are with a *segol* (Gen 7:12, etc.).